# Discovering dependencies of mod_jk

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, mod-jk

We are running a large amount of old EC2 instances which are based on [Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.09-release-notes/), a pretty old version.

We have recently built mod_jk on one of them that so that we can front Tomcat with Apache Web server 2.4.

We are in the process of identifying the dependencies of this mod_jk module. Can we re-use the mod_jk.so library that we just built with newer versions of the OS? We are running a large number of instances, so we would like to cut out the whole "building binaries from sources" step, so our ideal setup would be to take the current mod_jk.so binary and deploy it in all other EC2 instances.

The question is: can we safely do it? If not, when do we need to rebuild it? For example:

1. Do we need to rebuild it if we decide to launch EC2 instances with the [latest Amazon Linux AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2017.09-release-notes/), which is 3 years newer?
2. Do we need to rebuild it if the Apache's version is different?

Thank you in advance,
Meletis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of precompiled `mod_jk`'s in order to avoid just this cases. As per my own experience, I *must* recompile it in this scenarios:

1. Different Apache version (2.2/2.4)
2. Apache 32/64bits

As I stated before, according to this, you should have no more than 4 built `mod_jk` binaries to choose the right one from.

I could not tell you wether this is a *best* practice (probably not), but I have use this already built `mod_jk` in different Linux distributions and versions of Fedora, CentOS, Red Hat and Debian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @jlumietu. So, it looks like there is no dependency with the OS? I mean, your theory is that I can take my mod_jk.so and deploy in Ubuntu and it will work like a charm if the Apache is the same as the one I have in AWS? 

Is this an empirical knowledge, or do you have any links to documents to justify it?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. And of course, this is abolutely empirical knowledge, based on my own experiences with the different Linux distros I have tested with an `Apache httpd` - `mod_jk` environment. No, I have never read any document about this. But, from my point of view, it is worth a try, becuse it makes such a kind of deployments much more easier. At least, I allways try to avoid compiling and installing all the dependecies it needs in Production environments

Comment: Thank you! I will accept this answer if nothing else comes up in the next couple of days.

Comment: I suggest you to wait and check wether it actually works for the two versions of Amazon Linux AMI and only accept it in case it works. As I said, I have had success with several distinct Linux versions but I have not any experience with the right ones you requested about

Comment: Yes, I will try that too. I'm also a bit worried about OS security updates and patches. There may be a security update for Apache 2.4 tomorrow that will bump up it version number from 2.4 to 2.4.0001. Will mod_jk be affected and will need to be rebuilt, or will it be okay as long as the code base will still be "2.4"?